# Access Query Help(Query a Query)

Tags: sql, ms-access

I am working on a query and it is stumping me.

I have a table with a lot of proposals and they have a creation date of when the proposal was added to the database. I want to make a query based around a user choosing a state and then query only shows the most recently created proposal.

Example:

I have 4 Proposals. 2 from Delaware created on 1/1/2013 and 1/2/2013. The other 2 proposals are from Maryland created on 1/3/2013 and 1/4/2014. If the user types in Delaware then it should show the proposal on 1/2/2013 but if user types in Maryland it should show the proposal on 1/4/2013.

First, I tried this

```
SELECT *
FROM Opportunity
WHERE (((Opportunity.CreationDate)=
    (select max(Opportunity.CreationDate) from Opportunity)));
```

This works, it shows me 1 opportunity that has the latest date. So, that is half the battle. but when I tried to specify a state is where I am having trouble. It is Access so I thought creating a query that would prompt the user for the State and then go into a 2nd query that would query those results for the largest date field would work but it didn't.
So, what I have now is:

Query 1

`Select * FROM Opportunity` and it has a popup box appear that asks the user for the state. It then shows all the results for that state.

Query 2

`SELECT * FROM OpportunityByState WHERE (((OpportunityByState.CreationDate)=(select max(Opportunity.CreationDate) from Opportunity)));`

NOTE: I edited the SQL before posting here to use the all fields symbol(*) because Access wrote out every field and there is about 60 of them, so I didn't think anyone would want to see that wall of text.

Any suggestions would be great and I hope I provided enough information.

Answer (score 1):

By popup-box I assume you are referring to an Access Parameter. In which case, the following will show the most recent record(s) for the State entered in the parameter-box that appears. (I'm using a few field-names from my sample database.)

```
SELECT TOP 1 FirstName, Surname, Office, StartDate 
FROM Opportunity 
WHERE State=[Which State] 
ORDER BY CreationDate DESC;
```

It orders the records in descending order of the CreationDate, and grabs the first one. However, if there is more than one record with the same date, it will return all of these. (This is the way TOP n behaves in Access - it does not resolve duplicates.)

Comment: One easy (but not guaranteed) way to reduce the duplicates you mention is to store both date AND time in the CreationDate field.  Then you'd only have duplicates if 2 or more proposals were saved at the same date and time. Technically possible, but unlikely.

Comment: Thank you @PowerUser. I suppose if this were considered a too dramatic change to the current database, then an additional column could be created to store the time separately, and the date-and-time could be a calculated field where needed, in specific queries. (The calculation/addition may not be necessary, as long as the time is included in the output, and sorted DESC along with the CreationDate.)